# Regex for float number with length 5 and , or . separators

Tags: c#, regex, floating-point

I want to build a regular expression for float number with maximum Length 5.
My number can have separator ',' or '.' or it can be a natural number (not float)

I Want to allow any of this values

```
    XXXXX
    XXXX.X
    XXX.XX
    XX.XXX
    X.XXXX
    X.X
    X.XX
    X.XXX
    X.XXXX
    XX.X
    XXX.X
    etc.
```

Answer (score 9):

Simple method:

```
^\d{1,5}$|^(?=\d+[.,]\d+$).{3,6}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/48bKnf2MQkXsZFTQ)

Comment: Upvoting this clear answer that was never accepted... I've been noticing your fine regex work. You seem to have done a lot of tricky number validation lately. :)

Comment: If only debuggex was working.  Can't register to get unit tests...

Answer (score 0):

why not use c# condition? something like:

```
var x = 12345;
if (x.ToString().Length == 5 && x.ToString().Contains("."))
{
    //do something
}
```

**updated:**
*I've created a sample list that was like what you given above and make it list of double since int doesnt accept decimal .*

```
List<double> doubleList = new List<double>(new double[]
    {
        12345,
        1234.5,
        123.45,
        12.345,
        1.2345,
        1.2,
        1.23,
        1.234,
        1.2345,
        12.3,
        123.4,
    });

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var x in doubleList)
    {
        bool isNum = Regex.IsMatch(x.ToString(), @"^\-{0,1}\d+(.\d+){0,1}$");
        int countOfDot = Regex.Matches(x.ToString(), @"\.").Count;

        if (countOfDot == 1 && isNum) //number w/ decimal place
        {
            string[] spLitX = x.ToString().Split('.');

            if (spLitX[1].Count() <= 5) //float max of 5digits
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
        else if (countOfDot == 0 && isNum) //number w/o decimal place
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing . . .
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
12345
1234.5
123.45
12.345
1.2345
1.2
1.23
1.234
1.2345
12.3
123.4
```

Comment: Doesn't validate `1.2` for example.

Comment: @M42 , just add more validation and it will . . . answer updated

Comment: Answer not yet valid. You have to accept numbers like `1.2`.

Comment: Just read the question and see what OP wants to allow. In fact the number `1.2` is valid but you don't acept it.

Comment: That's better but you forget to validate also numbers with a comma instead of a dot. `12.345` must be valid and `12,345` must be also valid.

Comment: @M42 , i guess it will only work if the data given was converted into string ... e.g in my sample list of double convert to string and it will also work

Comment: It works because you're using a non escaped dot in `^\-{0,1}\d+(.\d+){0,1}$` and it will work even with input string like `12X34`. Also `{0,1}` can be written `?`.

Answer (score -1):

^\s*(([0-9]{1,3}.([0-9]{3}.)*[0-9]{3})|([0-9]+))(,[0-9]{1,2})?\s*$  should validate your needs 
EDIT 1 : this will validate : 
10000 
100000,33
1.000,13

And one more thing, you can edit it to fit your needs.
Hope this helps!